# remastersys created Live DVD hangs in "Choose a picture"

Tags: 11.10

I used remastersys to create a Live DVD. Then, I used the Live DVD for the installation on another computer. The installation hung at the "Choose a picture" session. Both the "Back" and "Continue" buttons were disabled. It seemed like the installation was hung. I had to power-cycle the computer and reinstall from the Live DVD again. After the power-cycle, the installation from the Live DVD went successfully.

Any idea why the installation hung at the "Choose a picture" session, and how to fix it without power-cycle the computer?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Disable the cam module `uvcvideo` and blacklist it, then you are good to go.

Comment: This answer would be improved by explaining *how* exactly to do this.